# Android service restarting

Tags: android, service

i have a remote service. I have a mainactivity that binds onresume and unbinds onpause. The service sends broadcasts like onstart oncreate and so on for the activity.

For some reason  my service gets restarted so it goes oncreate onstartcommand(no ondestroy) like 4 times in say a min and then all of a sudden it just settles down and runs for ever.

I put try catches around everything and nothing. i added a log.d onlowmemory aswell and nothing.

But here is the strange part it only happens when i have my phone plugged in(debugging).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System can kill any service or activity if only there is need for that. There are two things you can do:
Keep low - make sure, that your service use as small amount of memory and CPU as possible.
Tag your service as foreground - look into [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for example how to do that. It don't ensure that your service will not be killed, but rather shift it a bit in the line, so #1 advice is still actual.

Comment: hi. thanks. it just seems strange that it only happens in debug mode. Not much of a problem seeing that i added some code to handle restarts its just crappy that it does not call ondestroy if it restarts.

Comment: "Debug mode" uses some amount of system resources, so Android's appetite for processes termination increases.

Comment: yeah thats all i can think my eclipse is acting up lately.

Answer (score 0):

Services can be "started" services (in which you explicitly call Context.startService() and Context.stopService()) and/or "bound" services (in which you only call Context.bindService() and the service's lifecycle is controlled by the system). You can still call "bindService()" on "started" services if you need get connections to interact with them.

You mention you're binding to the service in the first paragraph, and in the second you say the service's onStartCommand() method is called.  onStartCommand() is called *only* when you're starting a "started" service.

How/where are you calling "startService()" in your application?

Comment: hi. I have menu option in activity to startservice